# Photoshop - Transparent backgrounds replaced by white?

Tags: adobe-photoshop-elements

I've literally just started using Photoshop tonight because I want to edit my mum into a photo of Michael Buble for a photocake. All was going well, I managed to cut out my mum and layer her over another photo, but I wanted to make another.
This time however, instead of having the transparent grey boxed background (meaning I can layer her onto another picture and still see the background of the picture), I have a white background. I don't know what's changed, but I need to get it back to the transparent one as I don't want my mum in a white box and then pasted over a picture of Michael Buble, I could do that in Word. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**Why this is happening**

A transparent image means, the image having a transparent background. i.e there is no background layer.

---

**How to save a transparent image ?**

You need to hide the background layer and/or any other layers that  acts as background/fill.

---

**Screenshots for reference**

[image]

[image]

---

**Save as *.png**

---

**Save for Web & Devices**

Make sure to toggle transparency, to add a transparent background. Other it will add background color as background

---

**Screenshot for reference**

[image]

Comment: Nice answer! Welcome to GD.SE :)

Answer (score 1):

Save the image as ".png", and you have to disable all the layers except the your mom's layer.